# Having hard time with my Ajax request in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to make an ajax request which would change the content of my select.

Here is my request :

```
    $(function() {
        $("#client").change(function() {
            type: 'GET',
            url: "jsonContacts.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                q: $("#client").val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                document.form.contactClient.options.length=0;
                document.form.contactClient.options[0]=new Option("Test", "test", true, false);
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                }
            }               
        });
    });
```

My form is :

```
<FORM name='devis' method='POST' action='ajoutDevisScript.php' id='form' onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
<p>
    <label for="client">Client</label>
    <input type='text' id='client' name='client' required>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="contactClient">Contact client</label>
    <SELECT name="contactClient" id="contactClient">
    </SELECT>   
</p>
</form>
```

I would like that when the text of 'client' change, the request change the data of my SELECT but, my test Option isn't displayed at all.

Thanks!

Comment: use   $("#contactClient").change(function() { } lable is not change bur dropdown in change

Comment: it doesn't work neither but, how can it get the change of client if I use $("#contactClient").change(function() { } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery already you can do it like this:

```
$('#contactClient').append($('<option>', {
    value: 'Test',
    text: 'test',
    selected: true
}));
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yz2qsyd2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going with jQuery might as well use it for populating the select too.

```
        success: function(data) {
            $("#contactClient").html("");
            $("#contactClient").append("<option value='test' selected>Test</option>");
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the keyup event beside the change event on textbox. You can do it like

```
$(function() {
    $("#client").keyup(function() {
        type: 'GET',
        url: "jsonContacts.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            q: $("#client").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(data,function(i,k){
                 html += '<option value="'+k.val+'">'+k.text+'</option>';
            });
            $('#contactClient').html(html);
        }               
    });
});
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: you override your variable `html` in each iteration